# Count pixels with certain indices that have a certain value in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors `xx` and `yy` holding the `x` and `y` indices of certain pixels respectively in matrix `A` . What I want to do is to check the values of the pixels with those indices and count how many of those pixels have the value `0`. For example, if `xx=[1 2 3]` and `y=[2 5 8]`, I want to check how many of these pixels(x,y) `(1,2), (2,5), (3,8)` have the value `0`. I can do this with for loops but I think it can be done easier in Matlab, so if anyone could please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
sum(A(sub2ind(size(A),xx,yy)) == 0)
```

First, you convert the row and column indices into single indices into the matrix A. Then, you check where A is zero for these indices (which will result in ones). Then you simply sum up the ones.

Answer (score 3):

A dirtier way than [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) is

```
 sum( A( [1 size(A,1)]*( [ yy; xx ] - 1 ) + 1 ) == 0 )
```

You can check [here](https://ideone.com/MySJXW)  and see that the dirty method is ~x4 times faster than `sub2ind`. So, if you are in need for speed, use the dirty method ;)

Comment: @user1460166 thank you for "accepting" my answer. However, I feel you should accept [user1809923`s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23801818/1714410): as it is more "canonic". I put my answer as an "extra" for advanced users, fresh users should start off with `sub2ind`...